# Disable link on username in comments?

Tags: 6, users, navigation, comments

How can I disable the link on authenticated an authenticated user's name in the comment submission form in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this out, not sure if it is the best way, but it works.  Create a really simple custom module and implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6).

**YOURMODULE.info**

```
name = YOURMODULE
description = Description of YOURMODULE goes here...
core = 6.x
```

**YOURMODULE.module**

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['_author']['#value'] = $form['author']['#value'];
}
```

Place these files in a directory named YOURMODULE, inside contrib modules directory. Then enable the module.

(Be sure to replace YOURMODULE with the name you choose to give to the module everywhere it occurs.)

Comment: I tried doing this but haven't met with much succes so far. I'll try again and let you know how it goes... thank you for your help, Laxman!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to make this change can be found here: [Three tips for comment theming in Drupal](http://www.kinetasystems.com/blog/three-tips-for-comment-theming-in-drupal)

Note: While this article is written for Druapl 5, it will work fine under Drupal 6 as well.